# Accessing 'Entity' From Another ViewController (Core Data)

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

another one ive been at for hours. Im having a major problem getting my app to 'see' my Entity in my database...

I have created code in my appDelegate to set up Core Data. The first view I boot to can access this data (read / write) with no problems. If I then try to access the database from another viewController its as if it doesn't exist.

I have all the correct @property's set up in my viewController header files:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

I have also got each viewController to be:

```
    NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
```

- I have imported the relevant header files in the .m files where I want to access the entity.

This is the error I get:

```
'+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name MyEntityName'
```

The confusing thing is that if I change the start up view from the appDelegate is has no problems seeing the Entity in whichever view controller I choose. It seems like it is 'injecting' it into the first one, but then thats it.

Im guessing I need to set up / alloc init a NSManagedObject and reference it back to my Entity, but I have no idea how to do this.

Any clues?

Thanks

Comment: How are you passing the managedObjectContext into the viewControllers? I see your property but are you actually assigning it?

Comment: Hi Paul... I dont think I am assigning them back to anything at the moment. How do I do this?

Comment: also... is it the 'right way' to pass the managedObjectContext around or am I supposed to create new ones for each viewController?

Comment: I generally pass it around. The only time I tend to make a new context is when I need to work in a background thread.

Comment: Assuming you create your controller in the appDelegate you would just do something like. `myViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;`

Comment: ahh I havent created / declared the other view controller in the appDelegate... only the first one I boot to... is this were I am going wrong?

Comment: So the first viewController works? How do you get from the first viewController to the others? Nope this sounds fine so far

Comment: yep the first one works... also if I change the self.rootViewController in the app delegate to another view - it works in whatever it is set to as well (this is what is confusing me)... Im using a UIButton and then seque action to get to the next viewController (the second one is a UITableViewController)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess what you need to do is pass the managedObjectContext like this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender;
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"theIdentifier"]) {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = (id)[segue destinationViewController];

        MySecondViewController *topViewController = [navigationController topViewController];
        topViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: ah I didnt realise you passed it around via segue's like other data... whoops!

Comment: nope :( its now saying: UINavigationController setManagedObjectContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: I have imported the header file that I want to segue to as well + the property in the next view controller is defiantly spelt correctly

Comment: Check my adjusted code it should account for you having the newViewController inside a `UINavigationController`